# ViewPager, the second fragment value equals the first one, dynamically loading

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have the following ViewPager which uses one fragment with dynamically loading data from Server. But the next value of fragment in ViewPager equals the previous. If to go 3rd value and turn back, all of values are getting the correct ones. How to get correct values at once?

```
    mPitchIdList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_PITCH_ID_LIST);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_view_pager);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            String pitchId = mPitchIdList.get(position);
            return MyQueryPitchFragment.newInstance(pitchId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mPitchIdList.size();
        }
});
```

Comment: set viewpager.setscreenofflimit(3);

Comment: I tried to use mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3) and other values. But the problem in Dynamically loading, it is making the next value equals the previous one.

Comment: then use uservisiblehint in each fragment to load data only when that fragment is visible

Comment: which one? oncreateView() in each fragment?

Comment: Yes, it is, I have the method performPitchRequest(pitchId), fragments use the same layout but different data which ones get from server using service

Comment: pichid is different for all other fragment?

Comment: Yes, it is. They are different

Comment: then chek logcat for each fragment recevied data.

Comment: I have checked, all of data are correct. The problem is in ViewPager, it caches MyQueryPitchFragment.newInstance(pitchId) for preload fragments and it shows the same information, but if you go to 3rd item and back to 2nd one you get the correct fragment information. And I do not know what I can do to make it work correct...

Comment: post activity code where you defined your viewpager and fragments

Comment: I think you were right, I should try to use setUserVisibleHint, it is going to help me. Thank you!